# Can an NMD90 8/3 cable be used instead of a 8/2

Tags: electrical

I have a pre-existing NMD90 8/3 cable running from the electrical panel to the basement bathroom. I decided to add a steam generator and build a steam room. The generator only needs a NMD90 8/2. Can I use the 8/3 cable to wire the generator and leave one wire unused?

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

Capped/wire nut both ends of the unused wire(probably red, or be weird and do black).

This is assuming the steamer is using 120v.  If it uses 240v without neutral, then cap/nut the white wire.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The steamer is using 240V so I will cap the white wire. Is this solution acceptable according to the code?

Comment: Yes for 240v that do not use neutral.  Older switch loops for lights used /2 cables and used the white as a hot, but recent code changes require a neutral be available in switch boxes so you need /3 cable and cap off the neutral if not needed, same idea as 240v not needing neutral.  It is there if you change your mind in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. You helped me a lot.